# How can non-binary data be tested for distinguishability from random?

Tags: probability, statistics, random, data-analysis, integers

Given a large string of Base-N digits (in other words, not necessarily binary), is there software or an algorithm that can output whether the data is reasonably pseudorandom or reveals a pattern?

In context, if one were to record and string together hundreds of thousands of results from a casino game, each taking a value of 0 through 5, what can be done to discover whether the results are pseudorandom, or intelligently designed to produce some unknown psychological effect on the gambler?  As such design hypotheses take almost any form one can imagine, a general solution or a solution testing a wide range of hypotheses would be required, as opposed to testing hypotheses one at a time.

Comment: I'd just try to compress the data, using `gzip`. If the compression ratio is high, then the data has a pattern to it, and if the data is random, then there will be no compression. Of course, there might be a pattern that `gzip` doesn't pick up on, yielding poor compression, so this test isn't perfect.

Comment: If this doesn't satisfy you, you may have to read up on the NIST statistical tests of randomness.

Comment: It looks like NIST is mostly for binary data.

Comment: The philosophy of the NIST tests extends to other bases.  For example, they test that there are (about) an equal number of $0$'s and $1$'s.  You should test that there are (about) an equal number of each digit.  You can compute the standard deviation of the number of a given digit and make sure the output is within reasonable limits.  Similarly, they test two bit strings, so you should test two digit strings.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, is there a program available that does this?